# Java escapes quotes in JSON strings

Tags: java, json, escaping

I've got a JSON string persisted in a DB (in a column of type *Text*), which I would like for clients of the server to be able to retrieve through a REST API.

Problem is that once the JSON string is retrieved by the backend and stored in a *String* object, ready to be returned to the client as part of the response body, Java automatically escapes the quotes.

So a JSON string persisted as:

`{"key1": "value1", "key2": "value2"}`

Would be retrieved and stored in a string object as:

`{\"key1\": \"value1\", \"key2\": \"value2\"}`

Then this escaped string would be returned to the client. My worry is that in the format that it is it won't be usable by the client.

I've seen some people using regex to remove the backslash, but I'm not sure how feasible that would be as a solution.

Any suggestions?

Comment: How are you sending the response to the client?

Comment: Can you show part of the code to retrieve the DB entry? Java doesn't automatically escape the quotes. If the string is persisted as you say, it should be retrieved without escaped quotes.

Comment: How exactly do you retrieve the string from database?

Comment: Are you sure that it is really escaped or just your debugger displays it this way?
can you print it to check?

Comment: I'm using Spring Boot and have a controller which returns a *ResponceEntity<MyObject>*. *MyObject* has multiple fields, one of which is the String field containing the JSON.

Comment: I'm sure it escapes the string, because I can see it in the response when I do *curl* or use Postman.

Comment: Also I can clearly with a DB client that it's persisted without escapes.

Answer (score 1):

You can use  `org.apache.commons.text.StringEscapeUtils` class for doing this. Please refer below code

```
String s = "{\\\"key1\\\": \\\"value1\\\", \\\"key2\\\": \\\"value2\\\"}";
s = StringEscapeUtils.unescapeJava(s);
System.out.println(s);
```

gives

```
{"key1": "value1", "key2": "value2"}
```

Comment: this is just a workaround - he should find source of the issue & eliminate it